AttributeError: 'Pipelinemodel' object has no attribute 'getFeatureImportance'
I need to register the model in unity catalog in Databricks. So, i trained the model with lightgbm.
from synapse.ml.lightgbm import LightGBMClassifier, LightGBMClassificationModel
Also, I registered the model in unity catalog as well using Mlflow. However, the problem is model inbuilt attribute is missing. I used mlflow.spark.log_model() and mlflow.pyfunc.log_model() to log & load model from unity catalog.
Except spark & pyfunc, none of the flavor didn't support with mlflow to register the model. Finally, the issue is half of model attribute is missing when we print the model after loading from UC.
Example: I can see full list print(dir(LightGBMClassificationModel)) but half of attribute is missing when i see after loading. model = mlflow.spark.load_model(model_uri)  then print(dir(model)). missing attribute example is "getFeatureImportances".
I checked version and runtime. However, I am not able to sort this issue.
I need to get all inbuilt function(attribute) when loading the model from Unity catalog. can anyone please advise or guide me on this issue.

Actually, mlflow.spark and mlflow.pyfunc is different from LightGBMClassificationModel.
When you log using mlflow flavours and load them agaiin you won't get the attributes from lightGBM.
According to this documentation you save it as native model and load it back the same way then you will get the expected attributes.
code
from synapse.ml.lightgbm import LightGBMClassificationModel

if running_on_synapse():
    model.saveNativeModel("/models/lgbmclassifier.model")
    model = LightGBMClassificationModel.loadNativeModelFromFile(
        "/models/lgbmclassifier.model"
    )
if running_on_synapse_internal():
    model.saveNativeModel("Files/models/lgbmclassifier.model")
    model = LightGBMClassificationModel.loadNativeModelFromFile(
        "Files/models/lgbmclassifier.model"
    )
else:
    model.saveNativeModel("/tmp/lgbmclassifier.model")
    model = LightGBMClassificationModel.loadNativeModelFromFile(
        "/tmp/lgbmclassifier.model"
    )



Thanks for your quick help.
Actually I want to register the model in unity catalog in databricks and load the model from there. can you please share your though on this. Thanks in advance.

Yeah you give the path to model.saveNativeModel("") like how you give to mlflow.spark.log_model(). same way you load it.
